# Is the Quadratic function $ f \left( x_1, x_2, x_3 \right) $ Convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms

Given the [Quadratic Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function) $ f \left( x_1,x_2,x_3 \right) $:

$$ f \left( x_1,x_2,x_3 \right) = 2x_1^2 - 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + 2x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3 - 3 $$

Is $ f \left( x_1,x_2,x_3 \right) $ convex?

Comment: The question is block, but it would be very easy to see by calculating the [Hessian Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) and check whether it is a [PSD Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix).

Comment: Could anyone lift the "On Hold" from the question?

Answer (score 1):

See that:

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1-x_2)^2+(x_1+1)^2+(x_3+1)^2-x_2-5$$

and

$$f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1-x_2)^2$$

$$f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1+1)^2$$

$$f_3(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_3+1)^2$$

$$f_4(x_1,x_2,x_3)=-x_2-5$$

are all convex functions.

Write

$$f=f_1+f_2+f_3+f_4$$

and apply the definition of convex function for each $f_i$.

Comment: how to apply definition of convex function for each

Comment: Do you know the definition? if $g$ is a convex function then $g(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y) \le \alpha g(x)+(1-\alpha)g(y)$.